# Renovate: Combine all updates to one branch/PR

Tags: config, pipeline, renovate

Renovate is updating the packages as soon as there is a new version. But renovate also creates a seperate PR/branch for each update. So if new versions released for 5 of my packages renovate will create 5 branches.
This leads to 5 pipelines, 1 PR is merged and the other 4 will rebase and run the pipeline again. So there will run 15 PR-pipelines + the pipeline for the `main` branch on each merge.
So all together there will run 19 pipelines.

Is it possible to combine – lets say all minor and patch updates – into one branch and PR to avoid the huge amount of PRs?

the only thing I found was the `prConcurrentLimit` which avoids the rebase and rerun of the PR-pipelines on each merge. But this will also trigger 10 pipelines.

If I can combine all together there is just 1 PR pipeline and 1 `main`-branch pipeline. So 2 pipelines in total. That would be awesome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can group updates together, for all nonmajor updates this can look like this:
(taken from the [renovate docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-group/))

```json
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ],
      "groupName": "all non-major dependencies",
      "groupSlug": "all-minor-patch"
    }
  ]
}
```